# Is this formula stable? $\frac{|x|-|y|}{x-y}$ as $x$ approaches $y$.

Tags: recursion, stability-theory

I want to analyze the stability of this formula $\frac{|x|-|y|}{x-y}$ as $x$ approaches $y$.
But this formula is not a recursion! I used to analyze the stability of recursion by computing the first n terms of this formula. 
Like this question: The integral
$$I_n=\int_0^1x^ne^xdx\quad n=0,1,2\cdots$$
suggests a recursion relation obtained by integration by parts:
$$I_n=[x^ne^x]|_0^1-n\int_0^1x^{n-1}e^xdx=e-nI_{n-1}$$
terminating with $I_0=e-1$. However, this algorithm, applied "forwards" for increasing $n$ is numerically unstable since small errors (such as floating-point rounding errors) are magnified at each step: if the error in $I_n$ is $\varepsilon_n$ such that the estimated value of $I_n$ is $I^{'}_n+\varepsilon_n$ then
$$\varepsilon_n=I_n^{'}-I_n=(e-nI_{n-1}^{'})-(e-nI_{n-1})=n(I_n-I_{n-1})=-n\varepsilon_{n-1}$$
and hence $|\varepsilon_n|=n!\varepsilon_0$. Even if the error in $\varepsilon_0$ is small, that in $\varepsilon_n$ is larger by a factor $n!$ which can be huge. So the propagation error is uncontrollable, that is to say,  this recursion is unstable.
But now I don't know how to verify the stability of this formula $\frac{|x|-|y|}{x-y}$ as $x$ approaches $y$.
Stability: If the error propagation is controllable, then the algorithm is said to be numerically stable.

Comment: What would qualify as "stability"? Are you asking if the limit exists, as $x \to y$ [through values other than $y$]?

Comment: @coffeemath I'm sorry, I should have written it more explicitly. I want to verify its numerical stability, that is to say, the error propagation is controllable.

Comment: That still seems vague (to me). I assume you want to take some cases wherein a numerical sequence of $x$ values approach a fixed $y$ value (where during approach never $x=y$) and describe it. But what does "error propagation" mean, that is how do you measure it, and what is meant by its being "controllable"?

Comment: @coffeemath Your assumption is correct, for your question, I edited my question again and added the error accumulation process. Hopefully, that will help you understand my question better.

Comment: You added error accumulation process for the family of integrals. But you're asking about the error accumulation in case of your single function of $x$ and $y.$ I still wonder how such error accumulation is defined for that function.

Comment: If $y=0$ this simplifies to $|x|/x$, which has different one-sided limits; if $y\ne0$, any $x$ close enough to $y$ to have the same sign has $\frac{|x|-|y|}{x-y}=\frac{|y|}{y}$, whose exact value requires only the sign of $y$.

Comment: @coffeemath Same question you had, I don't know how this formula defines error accumulation. So I don't know how to analyze its stability. I am so sorry, cause I don't know how to analyze the stability of an algorithm, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @J.G. So, from the point of view of numerical analysis, the formula is stable as x approaches y?

Comment: With the aforementioned $y=0$ proviso. More generally, $\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(y)$ is no problem, so long as $f'(y)$ exists. The real question, though, is this: when $x$ is within $\epsilon$ of $y$, how far is your function from its $x\to y$ limit? (As I said, if $x$ is close enough to $y$ to have the same sign, the error is $0$.) This has an especially nice answer when $f''(y)$ exists.

Comment: I'm not expert in numerical analysis. I can only suggest either contacting someone who is, or looking at numerical analysis literature in an attempt to find an example like yours of analyzing a function.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for your advice. I'll do it right now.

Comment: @J.G. I am so sorry, I still don't understand this sentence “The real question, though, is this: when  is within  of , how far is your function from its → limit?”.

Comment: Well, if you approximate the limit with a specific $x\approx y$, you might worry your choice of $x$ introduces a larger error, but happily it doesn't.

Comment: @J.G. I thought about your answer, you gave two scenarios, the first is  =0, the second is ≠0 and   close enough to  to have the same sign. But when x and y have different signs, and ≈, like x=-0.0001, y=0.0001. Does it lead to instability? (I'm sorry my English is not good)

Comment: @J.G. Thank you so much. With your help, I finally figured out this problem.